# Error al utilizar un for con jQuery y Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Busco que al ingresar valores a un `input` me cree la misma cantidad de imágenes en un canvas.

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
var distancia, aux = 0;
    for (var i =  0; i <arrText.length; i++) {
      parseFloat(arrText[i]);
      distancia = (arrText[i] + aux) / escala;
      aux = aux + arrText[i];
      var disxd = (aux - 250) / escala;
      var image = $('.screem');
      ctx.drawImage(image, 80 + disxd, 67);
    }
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error.

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
>     at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1700:11)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (<anonymous>:3:10315)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (<anonymous>:3:8342)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es porque al método `drawImage`, le estas pasando un `jQueryObject` y no un `HTMLImageElement`

### Solución:

Guardar en la variable `image` el primer elemento obtenido por el selector `$('.screem')`, es decir, `$('.screem')[0]`;

Ejemplo:

```
//... código ...
var image = $('.screem')[0];
ctx.drawImage(image, 80 + disxd, 67);
```